# JSON string containing \" after applying JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, json

I´m receiving a message that I have to parse to create a JSON object from a .NET application in javascript, but when I parse the message using the following instructions:

```
var messagePropertiesString  = JSON.stringify(messageObject.json);
var messageProperties = JSON.parse(messagePropertiesString);
```

The results contains a backslash, so I´m not able to convert it to a JSon object since it has the backslash.

```
{\"TravelNumber\":1,\"Unit\":\"g\",\"Weight\":0}
```

How can I remove the extra backslash?

Comment: messageProperties = messageProperties.replace('\\', ''); ?

Comment: with a RegExp : messagePropertiesString.replace(/\\/g,'')

Comment: But, for me, the problem is on the .NET application side ;)

Comment: That looks like the output of `JSON.stringify`.  `JSON.parse` should decode the escapes.  What is the original message?

Comment: Yes, probably is the way the serializer do its job, but that code is not at my side. I fixes using Lcf.vs recomendation.

Comment: Post a sample of `messageObject.json`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`messageObject.json` is already a string, so there is no need to stringify it, and when you do you get a string that would need to be parsed twice (the first parse will just undo the stringify and get you back a string of JSON) to get an object:

```
var messagePropertiesString  = JSON.stringify( messageObject.json );
var messageProperties = JSON.parse( JSON.parse( messagePropertiesString ) );
```

Instead, **you should** skip the stringify, and just parse it once:

```
var messageProperties = JSON.parse( messageObject.json );
```